# Report Viewer for MVC SyncFusion?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services, syncfusion

I was looking for the report viewer in Sync Fusion MVC reporting. But in the demo site and documentation, they are making it as button for export. After exporting
  they are asking us to do like operation. but i dont need that. i need to see the report in the browser itself. Is there any report viewer support for MVC in Sync fusion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion offers file format based Reporting solutions for ASP.NET MVC (and other .NET platforms) as file format based reports that can be generated on the server and streamed to the client to be opened by the respective viewer/application on the client. There are report viewers provided for PDF and Excel

a. MVC PDF Viewer for viewing PDF Reports within the browser.

http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/reporting/pdfviewer

b. Spreadsheet control in Silverlight for viewing Excel Reports within the browser.

http://silverlight.syncfusion.com/samples/Silverlight/#/User%20Interface%20Edition/Spreadsheet

Syncfusion also offers a Microsoft Report Definition Language (RDL) reporting solution. As part of this solution, Report Viewers for RDL are available for WPF and Silverlight.

An ASP.NET MVC RDL Report Viewer will be added in the 2012 Volume 4 release due in November 2012.